# How to use puppet's ensure_packages with my forked repository

Tags: puppet, sensu

I'm installing the latest `sensu-plugins-mysql` with the following puppet code successfully:

```
ensure_packages('sensu-plugins-mysql', { provider => sensu_gem, ensure => latest})
```

But I want to use my fork `nagyt234/sensu-plugins-mysql`, created from `sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-mysql`, how to do it? The `source` option doesn't work:

```
ensure_packages('sensu-plugins-mysql', { provider => sensu_gem, source => 'https://github.com/nagyt234/sensu-plugins-mysql.git', ensure => latest})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `sensu_gem` is not able to install a gem directly from a `github` repository, so the `sensu-plugins-mysql` was always installed from [rubygem.org](https://rubygem.org). **I had to generate my own gem** with a different name and publish it to [rubygem.org](https://rubygem.org).